# Pass attributes to method jQuery and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to post data (jQuery ajax) to a custom method in my controller so that I can build dynamic database queries, I am taking values from a dropdown menu and using them as my search queries.

My method

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController

  def rehomed(query={})
   Animal.where(query).to_json

    respond_to do |format|
     format.js {render :json => {} }
   end
  end

end
```

**Ajax call**

```
$('select.btn').on('change', function() {
 var animal_type = $('#animalType option:selected').text();
 var animal_town = $('#animalTown option:selected').text();

 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/public/rehomed',
   data: {
     animal_type: animal_type
   },
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
 });
});
```

So as an example if a user selects 'Cat' from the dropdown menu the query from my method should be

```
Animal.where(animal_type: 'Cat')
```

at the moment the query it is performing is

```
SELECT "animals".* FROM "animals"
```

which is just selecting every animal

How do I make this happen? what do I pass within `{render :json => {} }`

I'm trying to figure out how to put all this together.

Comment: I'm not sure about your action definition (accepting query parameter) but have you tried: `Animal.where(params)` to see if the right query is executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture and pass the result of the query. Use `params` to get the param information from the request.

```
def rehomed
  @animals = Animal.where(animal_type: params[:animal_type])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :json => @animals }
  end
end
```

Or in one line

```
def rehomed
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :json => Animal.where(animal_type: params[:animal_type])}
  end
end
```

Note I'm not calling `#to_json` given that `render :json` will convert the query result to json.

Comment: It won't work as `query ` in controller will have nothing but an empty hash, which means OP will end up having the current query: `SELECT "animals".* FROM "animals"` as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change jQuery to this:

```
$('select.btn').on('change', function() {
 var animal_type = $('#animalType option:selected').text();
 var animal_town = $('#animalTown option:selected').text();

 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/public/rehomed',
  data: { 'query': { 'animal_type': animal_type } }, // or 'name': animal_name etc
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

then in controller:

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController

  def rehomed
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js { render :json => Animal.where(params[:query]) } 
    end
  end

end
```

Note: queries as shown above may open a serious security issue, so do NOT do it unless you have a very strong reason or you know what you're doing.

If you don't change the jQuery shown above, then you will have to fetch the submitted value presented in params inside your controller like this :

```
  def rehomed
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js { render :json => Animal.where(:animal_type => params[:animal_type]) } 
    end
  end
```

Comment: You should probably filter your query, passing a full query object may open security issues. In fact, you will be able to pass a string and that will be injected as it is in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I agree. You can not trust the parameters being submitted to you on the internet. I'll write a note on that. Thanks.